# html div is not displaying its content text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel slider where i want to give model name to each image.So i use a `<div>` and put text into div. But the text is not displaying though background color of this div is visible.So need help .please.How to display the text?
my code sample goes here

**html**

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="body-content">
    <div class="carousel-nano" >
            <div id="demo5" class="scroll-img">
              <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img  src="jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/>
                        <div style="color:red;background-color:#000;">Text goes here</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#body-content .scroll-img {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
width: 890px;
height: 155px;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 0;
margin-top: 2px;
}
#body-content  .scroll-img ul {
  margin: 0;
  height: 58px !important;
  background:#123456;
}
#body-content .scroll-img ul li a img{
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
#body-content .scroll-img ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0 0px 0px;
  border-right: 10px solid #EEE;
}

#body-content #demo5.scroll-img ul {
  width: 1500px;
}
#body-content #demo5-btn {
  width: 680px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#body-content .carousel-nano{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
width:960px;
}
#search-image{
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
width: 66px;
height: 103px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2yxsrzg/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to increase font-size here

```
#body-content .scroll-img {
    font-size : 12px;
}
```

You have `font-size` zero in your fiddle.See updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2yxsrzg/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gautam3164

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#body-content .scroll-img {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  width: 890px;
  height: 155px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

to

```
#body-content .scroll-img {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  width: 890px;
  height: 155px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the thing i have noticed that, you have mentioned **font-size=0;** which is causing the problem to you.

***font-size is the attribute to set the size of the text you want to print on the screen as a result***.
so increase **font-size=5px;** atleast to see the result.

Rest is fine.
Thanks & Keep coding. :)